# How to pass the dataprocs metastore (dpms) in DataprocClusterCreateOperator

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, airflow, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-composer

I am trying to pass the DPMS config to `DataprocClusterCreateOperator` but not able to find the proper way to pass this configuration. Can anyone help me how to pass the dpms config in `DataprocClusterCreateOperator`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this code based on this [Documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-google/6.4.0/_modules/airflow/providers/google/cloud/operators/dataproc.html):

```py
import os
from datetime import datetime

from airflow import models
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.dataproc import (DataprocCreateClusterOperator,ClusterGenerator)
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule

#NV_ID = os.environ.get("SYSTEM_TESTS_ENV_ID")

DAG_ID = "dataproc_hive"

PROJECT_ID = "<your-proj-id>"

CLUSTER_NAME = "<your-cluster>"

REGION = "us-central1"

# Cluster definition
# [START how_to_cloud_dataproc_create_cluster]

CLUSTER_CONFIG = {
    "master_config": {
        "num_instances": 1,
        "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
        "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
    },
    "worker_config": {
        "num_instances": 2,
        "machine_type_uri": "n1-standard-4",
        "disk_config": {"boot_disk_type": "pd-standard", "boot_disk_size_gb": 1024},
    },
    "metastore_config":{
        "dataproc_metastore_service": "<path-to-your-metastore-service>/services/<your-metastore-service>"
    }
}


with models.DAG(
    DAG_ID,
    schedule_interval='@once',
    start_date=datetime(2022,7,7),
    catchup=False,
    tags=["example", "dataproc"],
) as dag:
    # [START how_to_cloud_dataproc_create_cluster_operator]


    create_cluster = DataprocCreateClusterOperator(
        task_id="create_cluster",
        project_id=PROJECT_ID,
        cluster_config=CLUSTER_CONFIG,
        region=REGION,
        cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,

    )


create_cluster
```

Created:
[image]

Logs:
[image]